# Textview doesn't update immediately in loop

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I have a for loop and at beginning every cycle I update textView. But textView always updates after code executes completely. I had an idea that I could update textView in another thread but I don't know if that would help. Is there any way around this so that it would update immediately ?

I am updating textView in first row of first loop.

```
public void searchWords(View v) {
    String chars = inSearch.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
    ArrayList<String> found = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
        loadingAtT1.setText(wordList.get(i));
        String left = chars;
        boolean ok = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < wordList.get(i).length(); j++) {
            boolean cont = left.contains(String.valueOf(wordList.get(i).charAt(j)));
            if (cont) {
                left = left.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(wordList.get(i).charAt(j)), "");
            } else {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ok) found.add(wordList.get(i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < found.size(); i++) {
        Log.i("result", found.get(i));
    }

    String toTextView = "";
    int display = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < found.size(); i++) {
        if (wordLength.getText().length() > 0) {
            if (found.get(i).length() == Integer.parseInt(wordLength.getText().toString())) {
                toTextView += found.get(i) + "\n";
                display++;
            }
        } else {
            toTextView += found.get(i) + "\n";
            display++;
        }

    }

    resultTextView.setText(toTextView);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Displaying " + display + " from " +
            found.size() + " words found to match.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you expect the textview to display every iteration or just the last?

Comment: Yes, I expect it to display (update) every iteration, but it updates just last iteration as it is right now.

Comment: code works MUCH faster than your eyes my friend. you will NEVER see that in a text view. You may want to store that into a list and then print the list.

Comment: Try to measure the execution time of each iteration. It looks like the UI thread does not have enough time to update the textView.

Comment: @DroiDev I thought that too, but app always freezes for about 4 second when executing that function so I don't think that's the case.

Comment: trust me, its the case. you wont see that happen. create a dummy app and just have a textview with a loop and change the textview to i. it wont display each iteration.

Comment: just put a marker in line `loadingAtT1.setText(wordList.get(i));`  to debug it and lets see what will happen.

Comment: @TDG I have measured average loop time of 0.0237 ms. But I have noticed in run log it says: `I/Choreographer: Skipped 103 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.` after running the function.

Comment: You can ignore that message, but loop time of 0.0237ms means over 40k iterations per second - we cannot see changes that happen that fast. Add a 0.2-0.3 seconds delay in the loop.

Comment: @TDG I've tried this before and now again, but that does not help. I outputted `wordList.get(i)` to console and with `Thread.sleep(300);` I could see it just fine, but textView updated only after the loop finished.